# Como saber a posição atual de um elemento na <option>

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Qual comando em javascript posso usar para pegar a posição do elemento atualmente selecionado nesta "lista" de options? Exemplo: Volvo = 0 (pois é o primeiro da lista, portanto imagino que seja 0) , saab = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar `selectedIndex`. Irá retornar o índice da `option` com a propriedade `selected`:

```js
var opt = document.body.querySelector("select").selectedIndex;
console.log(opt);
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Se quiser colocar um evento para pegar o índice ao mudar a seleção:

```js
var sel = document.body.querySelector("select");

sel.addEventListener("change", function(){
   var opt = this.selectedIndex;
   console.log(opt);
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: perdão, fiz uma edição,.é sobre o elemento que está selecionado atualmente. Exemplo: por padrão é o Audi, então se eu não mudar nada, deve retornar 0 que é sua posição

Comment: Ok! Resposta atualizada